# best way of storing session variable in asp.net mvc c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables

I have made an asp.net mvc web app.I am using

```
Session["UserId"] = UserId.ToString();
```

And i am getting UserId from different Controller.Sometimes it works fine in Visual Studio.But i deploy it IIS server.Sometimes i get object not set to an instance of an object.I am getting session variable by

```
int userId= Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"].ToString());
```

in different controller.Now i want to know is there any other best way of doing it?I want to avoid this error.

My web Config file as follow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLSERVER2008;initial catalog=Pollidut;user id=sa;password=sqladmin@123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PollidutEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.Model1.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.Model1.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLSERVER2008;initial catalog=Pollidut;user id=sa;password=sqladmin@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you want to avoid this error, you have to find the cause of this error and then fix it. The web.config isn't related to this.

Comment: I want to know the best way of using session in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session["UserId"]` will be null when the session expires, so you need to handle that case

```
if(Session["UserId"] != null)
    Session["UserId"] = UserId.ToString();
```

The web.config file is unrelated to this as @Serv said above.

Comment: is it the best way in asp.net mvc?

Comment: its the *only* way of storing a session in asp.net MVC. Whether it's the *best* way to do what you want to do is another matter